# Is there a more elegant way to search the station index?

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I work on a genetic algorithm for a robotic assembly line balancing problem (assigning assembly operations and robots to stations to minimize the cycle time for a given number of stations). The solution is represented by an ArrayList (`configuration`) which holds all the operations in the sequence assigned to different stations. Furthermore, I have two more ArrayLists (`robotAssignment`, `operationPartition`) which indicate where a new station starts and which robot is assigned to a station. For example, a solution candidate looks like this (`configuration`, `robotAssignment`, `operationPartition` from top to bottom):

```
Initial cycle time: 50.0
|2|7|3|9|1|5|4|6|8|10|
|2|1|3|2|
|0|2|5|7|
```

From this solution representation we know that operations 3, 9, and 1 are assigned to the second sation and robot 1 is used.

I need to keep track of the station an operation is assigned to. I tried a lot to store this in the Object `Operation` itself but I always ended up in problems and therefore I want to write a method that gives me the stations index of an operation.

Here is what I have coded so far:

```
// Get the station of an operation
public int getStation(Operation operation) {
    int stationIndex = 0;
    int position = configuration.indexOf(operation);

    for (int i = 0; i < GA_RALBP.numberOfStations ; i++ ) {
        if (i < GA_RALBP.numberOfStations - 1 &&    operationPartition.get(i) != null) {
            if (isBetween(position, (int) operationPartition.get(i), (int) operationPartition.get(i + 1))) {
                return stationIndex + 1;
            } else {
                stationIndex++;
            }
        }
        else if (i >= GA_RALBP.numberOfStations - 1 && operationPartition.get(i) != null) {
            if (isBetween(position, (int) operationPartition.get(i), configurationSize())) {
                return stationIndex + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// Check if value x is between values left and right including left
public static boolean isBetween(int x, int left, int right) {
    if (left <= x && x < right ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, this does not seem to be (a) very elegant and (b) if I have to do this for a large number of operations the runtime could become a problem. Has anoyone an idea how to solve this more efficiently?

Comment: There's no need for the isBetween method, the comparation is shorter than the invocation itself.

Why don't you just use a Map<Operation, Station> to map the stations?

Comment: Already thought about this but wasn't sure if I can treat the `Map` the same way like the `ArrayList` which I used so far. I will try it.

Comment: I would advise that you create a separate class for the solution (I assume this is contained in an Invididual of the population). If you need reverse search as well, use another reversed map or use a [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html).

Comment: `getStation()`  for Operations 3,9,1 is expected to return 1 because their indices {2,3,4} are in [2,5) ?

Comment: @RazvanManolescu What type of Map would you recommend? I started with a HashMapMap<Operation, Station> but it turnns out that I can no longer access an element by position. Should I use a LinkedHashMap and write accessor method or is there a better way?

Comment: @DavidSoroko Exactly (although I would increment the index by 1 to comply with the notation from the literature).

Comment: How do `GA_RALBP.numberOfStations` and `configurationSize()` relate to configuration and operationPartition ?

Comment: @DavidSoroko The number of station is given (in this example 4) but the number of operations that have to be assigned may change (in this example 10). Thus, `configurationSize()`will return 10 which is the length of `operationPartition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make the partitioning explicit (replaces your `operationPartition`) - something like:

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> operationToStationMapping = new HashMap<>();
    operationToStationMapping.put(2,0);
    operationToStationMapping.put(7,0);
    operationToStationMapping.put(3,2);
    operationToStationMapping.put(9,2);
    operationToStationMapping.put(1,2);
    operationToStationMapping.put(5,5);
    operationToStationMapping.put(6,7);
    operationToStationMapping.put(8,-1);
    operationToStationMapping.put(10,-1);
```

Then getStation() becomes:

```
getStation(int operation) {return operationToStationMapping.get(operation);}
```

Comment: But wouldn't `getStation` return `stationIndex` 2 for operations 3, 9, and 1 or 5 for operation 5? I guess I would have to map the station and in this case I would no longer need a `getStation` method?!

Comment: Yes, if this is incorrect just `put` the correct value e.g.
    operationToStationMapping.put(3,1);
    operationToStationMapping.put(9,1);
    operationToStationMapping.put(1,1);

Comment: Alright! Thanks a lot. Hope to get this running now!

Comment: Cool, probably better to name this map `operationPartition` as in your original solution.